# Taco Seasoning + Mustard smells like pickles

Tags: seasoning, pickles

I made chicken burgers seasoned with taco seasoning mix, black pepper, and mustard. After letting it marinate on the meat for a while there was a strong sent of pickles. What might be causing it to smell of pickles?

Comment: Mustard and onions are common pickle flavorings, so you might be picking up on that.  But taco seasoning usually has cumin, whereas pickles usually have turmeric

Comment: Just to clarify: define “a while”, please? Did you store the seasoned meat in the fridge or on the counter?

Comment: @Stephie It was stored in the fridge after I put it on the tray.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that what you actually smell is the mustard seed, but because mustard seed is such a common ingredient in pickles, you've associated the smell as being the smell of pickles.